# is @Singleton on a class the same as an object in Scala?

Tags: scala, class, singleton

I came across a piece of code in Scala that looks like this:

```
@Singleton
class MyClass {
    // ...
}
```

But I thought objects were Singletons and classes were not. So is this basically equivalent to this?

```
object MyClass {
    // ....
}
```

EDIT: Here is [what I'm looking at](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-starter-example/blob/master/app/controllers/AsyncController.scala).

Comment: Your @Singleton could be an annotation of any library. Please specify which library/import is used.

Comment: I posted the Github link

Comment: A similar question has already been asked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282792/why-use-singleton-over-scalas-object-in-play-framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. By itself, the `@Singleton` annotation does absolutely nothing. It is meant to be used by a dependency injection (DI) framework. `@Singleton` signals to the DI framework that it should only instantiate one instance of that class if another class (or many) calls for it as a dependency.

There is nothing stopping you, however, from simply instantiating more instances of `class MyClass` manually.

With `object MyClass`, you have a singleton created and enforced by the Scala compiler.

Comment: Does that mean `@Singleton` on an `object` is redundant? Or more specifically, `object` implies `@Singleton`, but `@Singleton` does not imply `object`?

Comment: @user3685285 Kind of. It just wouldn't do anything. `@Singleton` on an `object` would be ignore by a DI framework, because DI frameworks are only concerned with constructing classes.

Answer (score 9):

`@Singleton` usually refers to a managed singleton in an IOC (Inversion of Control) framework, like Guice (see [Scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes)) or Spring.

That's a difference to `object`, which is a singleton managed by the ClassLoader.

In theory, you can have multiple applications running at the same time, using different `@Singleton` objects of the same class. But they will all use the same `object` as long as they share a ClassLoader.